# Sometimes sensor doesn't handle MDS requests

Tags: movesense

I'm working with Movesense 2.0.0 on a HR+ sensor and the latest MDSlib for Android.
I have an App that calls my custom WB services to download some data stored on sensor's EEPROM.
It happens that sometimes (once every few hundred calls, not always on the same endpoint and when it happens it keeps doing it for a few subsequent requests) sensor's requests handler is not called, and I get this messages from debugger:

```
ERROR: SF-N invalid CRC
ERROR: SF-N frame too short
ERROR: SF-N invalid CRC
```

Usually if I send the request again after a few seconds it's correctly handled.
I also tried sending hundreds of thousands of requests from wbcmd through serial port, but the error never appeared.

Is there something I can look at to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CRC error indicates that the datapipe experienced dropping or incorrect data, which was caught by the whiteboard protocol CRC checks. Corruption usually happens when the radio link is on the verge of dropping completely and there really is not much that can be done.

You can read the radio link RSSI value (signal strength) in both iOS and Android to see bad the connection is. Most of the time I don't bother. Easier just to retry failed operations later.

*Full Disclaimer: I work for the Movesense team*